# Hadoop Custom Output format, when do all reducers end?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce, outputformat

I'm building a custom output format for hadoop and was wondering if there is a way in the output format to know when all reducers (RecordWriters) are complete ?

In order to know that one RecordWriter completed, the close method of RecordWriter can be used, but what about executing some cleanup when all of the RecordWriters complete ?

Comment: what kind of clean up do u need ?

Comment: I have created a record in the database and I need to delete it at the end of the MR job, so that's why I'm asking when do all the reducers end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the driver itself to do the final clean up instead of relying on the `OutputFormat`. I doubt if it really provides such a feature(api). The `finalize` method may be the last resort, but not advisable at all.

The `waitForCompletion` method of `Job` returns only after the jobs finishes. So simply do it as :

```
boolean status = job.waitForCompletion(true); 
if(status){
     // clean up required for successful jobs
} else {
     // clean up required for failed jobs
}
```

If your clean up is irrelevant to the job's success/failure, just remove the `if-else` part. And if you really need a method in your `OutputFormat` class to do the deletion, make it `static`. eg :

```
job.waitForCompletion(true);
CustomOutputFormat.cleanUp();
```

I hope this should suffice your need.

Comment: I tried this solution and it it's the best I have so far, but what I wanted to do is do a cleanup independent of the job running and this won't achieve it. I didn't see anything in the API that mentions that this is supported.